# Possible try/catch and memory management issue?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, try-catch

I have a large Java app that processes a large collection of data files, using a try/catch within an actionPerformed (sample code below). It runs out of memory when I get to about 1000 files inside the loop.

Each file load legitimately takes about 1MB of storage, but I've looked carefully and don't see any place where that storage is being hung on to. Each file load is doing just the same thing (ie assigning the same vars), so it ought to be re-using, not accumulating.

I tried inserting an explicit gc call into the loop, which (according to visualvm) succeeds only in smoothing out the spikes in memory use (see image below).

The odd thing is the behavior of memory use: as the attached image makes clear, the usage climbs while the loading loop is working, persists at the plateau while inside the try, but the gc outside the try causes all the memory to reclaimed (the cliff at the end of the plateau).

Is there something about try/catch that influences gc behavior? Any hints about things to check in my code to find a possible leak that I might have introduced?

I've spent many hours on this with a variety of memory/heap management tools, and tracing code, and it's really got me bewildered. If it were a true memory leak in my code, why would the final gc clean up everything?

Many thanks for any suggestions/ideas.

```
if (message == MenuCommands.TRYLOADINGFILES){
try {
    File dir = new File(<directory with 1015 files in it>);
    File [] cskFiles = dir.listFiles(ioUtilities.cskFileFilter);
    for (int i=0; i<cskFiles.length; i++){
            loadDrawingFromFile(cskFiles[i], true);
            if (i % 10 == 0) System.gc();
    }
    DebugUtilities.pauseForOK("pausing inside try");
}
catch (Exception e1){
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
DebugUtilities.pauseForOK("pausing outside try");
System.gc();
DebugUtilities.pauseForOK("pausing after gc, outside try");
}
```

where

```
public static pauseForOK(String msg){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg, "OK", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

[image: visualvm memory graph]

Followup based on suggestion from Peter, below. histo:live shows almost NO change no matter when run (at pgm startup, before any actions taken, after all files read (when visualvm reports GB of storage being used), after final gc, when visualvm says it's back down to initial stg use). From startup to running the first four categories about double, and the amount of Char stg goes up by about the amount expected for one file processing, but not much else changes.

According to it, it looks like nothing is sticking around. Here are the first 30 or so lines of the histo from just after when the file load loop finishes (before the final gc outside the try).

```
 num     #instances         #bytes  class name
----------------------------------------------
   1:         67824        9242064  <methodKlass>
   2:         67824        9199704  <constMethodKlass>
   3:          6307        7517424  <constantPoolKlass>
   4:          6307        6106760  <instanceKlassKlass>
   5:         46924        5861896  [C
   6:          5618        4751200  <constantPoolCacheKlass>
   7:         10590        3944304  [S
   8:         19427        3672480  [I
   9:         15280        1617096  [B
  10:         33996        1584808  [Ljava.lang.Object;
  11:          2975        1487144  <methodDataKlass>
  12:         40028        1280896  java.util.Hashtable$Entry
  13:         45791        1098984  java.lang.String
  14:         31079         994528  java.util.HashMap$Entry
  15:         10580         973472  [Ljava.util.HashMap$Entry;
  16:          6750         817344  java.lang.Class
  17:         10427         583912  java.util.HashMap
  18:          1521         523224  javax.swing.JPanel
  19:         10008         516344  [[I
  20:          8291         457176  [Ljava.security.ProtectionDomain;
  21:          4022         431800  [Ljava.util.Hashtable$Entry;
  22:           774         377712  com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsScrollBarUI$WindowsArrowButton
  23:           689         369704  [J
  24:         13931         334344  java.util.ArrayList
  25:          7625         305000  java.util.WeakHashMap$Entry
  26:          8611         275552  java.lang.ref.WeakReference
  27:          8501         272032  java.security.AccessControlContext
  28:         16144         258304  javax.swing.event.EventListenerList
  29:          6141         245640  com.sun.tools.visualvm.attach.HeapHistogramImpl$ClassInfoImpl
  30:           426         245376  <objArrayKlassKlass>
  31:          3937         220472  java.util.Hashtable
  32:         13395         214320  java.lang.Object
  33:          2267         199496  javax.swing.text.html.InlineView
```

It shows basically this same thing no matter at what point in the process it's run. Got basically the same result even without the :live argument. Yet the program definitely will run out of memory if it runs on enough files.

One other item: I took two snapshots using visualvm's Memory Sampling, one at pgm starup and one on the plateau of memory use; the delta shows the expected increase in storage use, including an increase in the count of some structures that's exactly the same as the number of files processed. As each file processing creates one of those structures, it's as if all that intermediate storage is being kept around while inside the try, but can be cleared out afterward.

What's going on?

++++++++++++

Update 22:00 EDT Sunday

Thanks to @Peter Lowrey, @Vampire, and others for suggestions. Tried all those ideas and nothing works. Tried setting -XX:NewSize=1GB and -XX:NewRatio=3, but it didn't help.

The try/catch was a holdover from the original code and is (I belatedly realized) irrelevant in the example.  Getting rid of it entirely changes nothing. Just the simple for-loop loading the files causes the same memory growth pattern, followed by the drop
to initial values when the final gc is done.

Following up on @Vampire's suggestion, I tried this variation (with the loads inline, rather than in a block):

```
loadDrawingFromFile(thecskFile, true);
loadDrawingFromFile(thecskFile, true);
... 20 times
DebugUtilities.pauseForOK("after 20 loads, before gc");
System.gc();
DebugUtilities.pauseForOK("after gc outside try");
```

The 20 file loads produced proportionally the same amount of growth in Used Heap space (about 400MB) as in the full example, then after the System.gc() above, the heap space used drops instantly back to program initialization levels, just as before.

When that happened I tried an even more basic approach

```
loadDrawingFromFile(thecskFile, true);
DebugUtilities.pauseForOK("after load ");
System.gc();
.. repeated 20 times
```

Turns out this work, in the sense that the memory usage never goes 50 MB even after 20 file loads.

So this seems to have to do with threads and thread interruption. Which leads me to mention one more fact: this is an application that runs off a GUI that's started with:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   public void run() { ... }
}
```

I'm not that familiar with threads and the Swing Utilities, so perhaps this is some form of naive mistake, but it seems to come down to the fact that a lot of non-live objects are not being touched by the gc until the ShowMessageDialog interrupts something.

Additional suggestions welcome.

Comment: Don't put it in a try-catch. It's probably messing with the garbage collection.

Comment: Or put the try catch inside the for loop...

Comment: Please, could you post the code inside `loadDrawingFromFile`?  Maybe there is something useful there

Comment: The content of loadDrawingFromFile is required.

Comment: Which objects are being retained? Try ` jmap -histo:live {pid} | head -33`

Comment: Jorge_B, weston: code for loadDrawingFromFile is way too big (lots of user-interface and display management), so it wouldn't be helpful to post. Important point is that it opens the data file, creates lots of data structures (char, TreeSets, strings, etc.), then closes the file.

Comment: Can you try increasing you new size to reduce the chance of premature promotion (of small objects anyway)

Comment: Your `jmap` suggests nothing much is retained, the problem is that your temporary working set is ending up in the tenured space.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: Sorry, don't know how to "inrease new size", or how to deal with temp working space getting into tenured space. Are these handled via arguments to the JVM (if so, what args?), or?

Comment: You can try `-Xmn1g` to set the new size to 1 GB.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you don't have a memory leak.  Instead you have having premature promotion of large objects.

If you are creating large objects, e.g. byte[], these go straight in the tenured space.  These are only cleaned up on a major or full collections.  Most likely you are only triggering minor collections do the large objects are not being freed until a full collection is triggered.

Comment: @user1359010 you can only trigger a full collection with System.gc(); I would consider recycling your buffers or byte[] and it might not be a problem.

Comment: You cannot trigger any kind of garbage collection. System.gc() just kindly asks the VM to do a garbage collection, but there is no guarantee whatsoever that System.gc() will have any effect at all. Did you try my suggestions?

Comment: @Vampire While there is no guarantee, in practice the OpenJDK and HotSPot JVMs will do a full collection every time by default.  This can be changed on the command line.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: Tried setting -XX:NewSize=1GB and -XX:NewRatio=3, but it didn't help. See update to original, above. Anything else you can suggest? Tnx.

Comment: @user1359010 When you say `it didn't help" I am not convinced there is a problem in the first place. Your GC only runs when it needs to, and it's not clear that it needs to run.

Comment: @Peter: I didn't make it clear - I get an OOME exception eventually (not shown in the examples posted). No question that memory is being used up. I found it interesting that it could in fact be reclaimed before the OOME if there was a JOptionPane.showMessage.  I'm wondering now if this is a Swing issue; I've read reports of memory leaks in eg JFrames, and loading each file results in resetting the display. Visualm's mem sampling shows old (unreachable) Panels being kept around, which would suggest a problem in my code, except that they do get instantly gc'd after the pauseForOK.

Comment: @user1359010  The amount of memory really used is the memory usage after a FullGC.  Any other figure is just an indication of how much garbage you have + real memory.  If you want to see how the memory is really increasing, look at how much is used after each full GC.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: yes, I understand about measuring memory usage. The bottom line here is the OOME exception that inevitably occurs. The graphs were just to show the progress of the problem. The program is crashing with OOME, so the memory is unquestionably not being reclaimed. Thanks for your suggestions. I'm going to look into whether Swing is the problem here.

Comment: @user1359010 In that case you need to look at how much memory is used after a Full GC, and in your graph it is very little so it doesn't demonstrate your problem.  You need to look at what is happening just before an OOME.  You can trigger a heap dump on OOME to see what was using all the memory.

Answer (score 0):

I guess Peter is right, but in case he isn't: You can run out of file descriptors by not closing streams in `loadDrawingFromFile`. IIRC it manifests itself also by OOM, while you can have tons of free memory. I guess it's not what's happening in your case as the exception message should state it clearly.

Comment: @Maartinus: thanks for the suggestion, but using visualvm I can see memory inexorably growing from the very first file load. So it's not that I run out of descriptors; I eventually run out of memory and I can see it coming as the used heap size grows.

Comment: @user1359010 Then I guess, my first guess was right. :)